# Unknown SMTP host: smtp.outlook.com

Tags: outlook, smtp, jakarta-mail

I made an application which requires to send emails. It worked before, but when I wanted to run it today, it threw an `java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.outlook.com`. It used to work friday, did something change in the outlook configuration?

This is my code:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smpt.host", "smtp.outlook.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    try {
        transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        try {
            transport.connect("smtp.outlook.com", username, wachtwoord);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It throws the following error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.outlook.com;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.outlook.com
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1932)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at retourberichten.VerstuurEmail.SendEmail.VerstuurTest(SendEmail.java:143)
    at retourberichten.StartApplicatie.App.main(App.java:46)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.outlook.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:288)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:231)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
    ... 5 more
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected
```

Any help is really appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: If you are having a problem connecting to something you used to be able to connect to the first thing I would check is if that something is still there.  There are things that could have changed like firewall rules. Is the server still up etc.  Try pinging (not always the best test) or try to telnet to the host and port, try doing a tracert. In short ensure the host is still reachable. And make sure you do it from wherever the application is hosted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SMTP server should be smtp.live.com rather than smtp.outlook.com

http://www.groovypost.com/howto/outlook.com-settings-pop3-smtp-imap/